# how to make multiple api calls in one action (one button)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an api call to fetch some astronomy data f  and an api call to fetch weather data from openweather , i would like to combine them into one function , so that when the user clicks the search button it will display data from both the api calls but am not sure how to achieve this. I tried the below but its not working. Any help is greatly appreciated.!

layout.js

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Weather from './Weather';
import Form from './Form';
import Nav from './Nav';
import './layout.css';
const API_KEY = "";

class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.props;

    this.getTrail=this.getTrail.bind(this);
       this.getDate=this.getDate.bind(this);
  }



  getTrail = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();


    const city = e.target.city2.value;
    this.setState({
      show: !this.state.show
    });

    const country = e.target.country.value;


    const api_call = await fetch(`https://api.wunderground.com/api/b1049a092a7f69ea/astronomy/q/${country}/${city}.json`);
    const api_call2 = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);

const data2 = await api_call.json();
    const data = await api_call.json();

    if (city) {
      this.setState({
        moon_phase: data.moon_phase.ageOfMoon,
        moon_hour: data.moon_phase.hemisphere,
        moon_rise: data.moon_phase.moonrise.hour,
        moon_rises: data.moon_phase.moonrise.minute,
        moon_state: data.moon_phase.phaseofMoon,
        moon_set: data.moon_phase.moonset.hour,
        moon_sets: data.moon_phase.moonset.minute,
        sunset: data.sun_phase.sunset.hour,
        sunsets: data.sun_phase.sunset.minute,
        sunrise: data.sun_phase.sunrise.hour,
          temperature: data2.main.temp,
        city: data2.name,
        clouds: data2.clouds.all,
        main: data2.weather[0].main,
        icon: data2.weather[0].icon,
        rain: data2.rain,
        pressure: data2.main.pressure,
        humidity: data2.main.humidity,
        description: data2.weather[0].description,
        sunrises: data2.sun_phase.sunrise.minute,
         error: ""


      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        moon_phase: undefined,
        sunset: undefined
      });
    }


var clouds = data.clouds.all;

    if (clouds > 30) {
      this.setState({
        msg: " Poor  conditions for stargazing!! "
      })
    }
    else {

      this.setState({
        msg: " Good conditions for stargazing! no rain in forecast! "
      })
    }

  }
  getDate() {
    var date = new Date().getDate();
    var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();

    this.setState({ date, year, month });

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDate();
  }

  render() {
     return(

      <div>
    <br></br><br></br><br></br> <br></br><br></br><br></br>
    <Nav />


    <p> Search bellow </p>
      <div className="c">

    <div className="row">

<br></br><br></br>
      <div id="city">


 <h3> {this.state.msg} </h3>








                  <Weather className="fish"
                    city={this.state.city}
                    temperature={this.state.temperature}
                    humidity={this.state.humidity}
                 clouds={this.state.clouds}
                       pressure={this.state.pressure}
                    description={this.state.description}
                    rain={this.state.rain}
                    icon={this.state.icon}
                    error={this.state.error}
                  />

      <div className="date"><p id="d"> {this.state.date}/{this.state.month}/{this.state.year}</p> 


<div>
    <Form getTrail={this.getTrail} />






              {this.state.moon_phase &&   <div> moon_phase: {this.state.moon_phase}</div>  }
               {this.state.sunset && this.state.sunsets && <div className="row"> <p> sunset Time: {this.state.sunset} </p> : <p> {this.state.sunsets} </p> </div> }

               {this.state.sunrise && this.state.sunrises &&  <div className="row"> <p> sunrise  Time: {this.state.sunrise} </p> : <p> {this.state.sunrises} </p></div> }

                   {this.state.moon_set && this.state.moon_sets && <div className="row"> <p> moonset:  {this.state.moon_set} </p> : <p> {this.state.moon_sets} AM</p> </div> }

                <div className="w-100"> </div>
                  {this.state.moon_rise && this.state.moon_rises &&    <div className="row">     <p>moonrise - {this.state.moon_rise} </p> : <p> {this.state.moon_rises} PM</p> </div> }



               {this.state.moon_state &&   <p> {this.state.moon_state} moon  </p> }
               {this.state.moon_hour && <p> hemisphere: {this.state.moon_hour} </p>  }
 </div>

 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
 </div> 
 </div>

 );
  }
}
 export default Layout;
```

form.js

```
import './App.css';

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Form = props => (



    <div className="wrap2">
          <div className="form-row align-items-center">


          <div className="col-auto">
        <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={props.getTrail}>


            <label htmlFor="email">City</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"  id="inlineFormInput" name="city2" placeholder="City..." />

            <div className="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                <div className="input-group-addon"></div>
            </div>

            <label htmlFor="email">State</label>

            <input type="text" step="any" className="form-control" name="country" placeholder="State.." /> <br></br>
            <br></br><br></br>
            <button className="btn btn-success">Search</button>

        </form>

    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
);




export default Form; 



export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in layout.js your data and data2 are the same. you pointed to same api call

Answer (score 1):

Use `Promise.all`.

```
const [data, data2] = Promise.all([api_call.json(), api_call2.json()])
```

Comment: As you are doing the `async/await`, the second call waits until the first one to finish to start. Using `Promise.all` both will runs in parallel